# IE injects VBScript tags in the middle of rendering, causing malformed HTML

Tags: html, internet-explorer, plugins, vbscript

For some reason, it seems like IE9 (I believe IE8 too, but not sure), is injecting

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=VBScript>on error resume next pluginFound = IsObject(CreateObject("DIFFERENT PLUGIN EVERY TIME"))
```

in the middle of my content without any regards to surrounding context. This means it gets added in the middle of an attribute, or in the middle of some JavaScript, causing the HTML to be malformed and causing all sorts of problems.

This happens on multiple computers with different plugins, so it's not machine specific. And it's also not consistent: the location in which the offending script gets injected varies, the offending script varies. Sometimes you'll get several page loads without a problem and then you'll get the broken HTML.

[image: Developer Tools]

My page is using a fair amount of JS, but nothing crazy. It's currently using jQuery, Google Maps, Bootstrap, Google Tag Manager, and loading a couple of Twitter, Google+, Facebook Iframes with their own little JS snippets. So, there are some asynchronous callbacks happening, but I wouldn't think this would interfere with how the browser renders the DOM and when it decides to inject plugin code.

You can see the problem if you reload http://www.rew.ca/properties/search/839721 enough times. If you scroll to the bottom of the page, you'll see raw JSON, or sometimes just some random HTML snippet will show in the middle of the page (because of mismatched tags).

Any ideas of why these scripts get injected arbitrarily and how to work around that?

Thanks

[UPDATE]
Here's another example of the script tags getting included in the middle of HTML content:
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this with any amount of refreshing.  Have you tried viewing the site with plugins disabled for IE?

Comment: I can't reproduce it on an IE9 on W7 in a Virtual Machine, even though I've added Flash and Adobe PDF link helper. But on several other machines (some with a basic install, only "factory" plugins) it still occurs. Not sure if it happens with disabled plugins, but I'll give that a try. However, I can't ask users to disable plugins to visit my site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the problem lies in the http://cn.clickable.net/js/cct.js script, and specifically in the `IsIEPlugin` method of the `__cct_tracker` class:

```
this.IsIEPlugin = function (e) {
  var t = !1;
  return document.write('<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=VBScript>\n on error resume next \n pluginFound = IsObject(CreateObject("' + e + '")) </SCR' + "IPT>\n"), t ? 1 : 0
}
```

This method is called several times, with different arguments:

```
this.pixelRequestParams.cctDir = this.IsIEPlugin("SWCtl.SWCtl.1"),
this.pixelRequestParams.cctFlashPlugin = this.IsIEPlugin("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.1");
if (this.IsIEPlugin("PDF.PdfCtrl.1") == 1 || 
    this.IsIEPlugin("PDF.PdfCtrl.5") == 1 || 
    this.IsIEPlugin("PDF.PdfCtrl.6") == 1) 
  this.pixelRequestParams.cctPdf = 1;
this.pixelRequestParams.cctQuickTime  = this.IsIEPlugin("Quicktime.Quicktime"),
this.pixelRequestParams.cctRealPlayer = this.IsIEPlugin("rmocx.RealPlayer G2 Control.1"), 
this.pixelRequestParams.cctWmPlayer   = this.IsIEPlugin("wmplayer.ocx")
```

I suppose (even I'm not sure) that "cct" stands for "Clickable Conversion Tracking", so it must be some sort of tracking code.
After further investigations, I've determined that the "cct.js" script gets loaded by the [Google Tag Manager](http://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2772432?hl=en) (GTM) script [http://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js](http://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-X9BN).
So, if I'm not wrong, by removing the GTM code snippet from your HTML page, you should be able to solve the problem.
It seems that the VBSCRIPT code dynamically injected by the GTM JavaScript code sometimes is not executed, but don't ask me why, since I don't really know.

Comment: Nice find! I had actually come to the conclusion that it had to do with GTM as well (by process of elimination, removing chunks of code from the page, not as detailed as your finding). The strange thing is that is it seems to have stopped happening, or at least the errors reduced in frequency. I'm not sure if someone changed something on the GTM configuration side.